# IntelliJ Debugger catching wrong file with same name

Tags: java, maven, debugging, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I have two files with same name in two separate packages *package1* and *package2* in same maven project. I added a debug point at line *i* in the file that is present in *package1*. But while debugging, the IntelliJ IDEA debugger stops at line i of the file present in *package2*. This has been occurring with a few of my fellow mates as well. Is there any such bug reported with IntelliJ ? Any fix or workaround ?

Comment: That's hard to belive. As a pragmatic programmer would say: _**select Isn’t Broken** It is rare to find a bug in the OS or the compiler, or even a third-party product or library. The bug is most likely in the application._

Comment: @Puneet Chaurasia then the code you are debugging should run both files in that situation right (2 files in packages A & B). What will display when you click 'view break points' (two red bulbs) or Ctrl+Shift+F8 on debug tool window?? You see breakpoints on both files???

Comment: @SupunWijerathne : The debugger stops at same line number in file present in B where i have put the debug point in that of A. Even when there is no executable code on that line there. So i am very certain that its executing the correct code (as it should) but showing the debug control point wrong.

Comment: @PuneetChaurasia very strange. How on earth it stops on not executing code? Either you misunderstood something or something going really wrong. Btw what's on 'view break points'??

Comment: @SupunWijerathne Looks like there is a file with same name in different modules (having same package name) debugger could sometimes not figure out which one is currently in execution. This seems to be fixed in later updated of IntelliJIdea 2016.

Comment: It's 2023 and the IntelliJ bug is still there. Fortunately it allows us to select alternative source for the same, but it's strange that it has problems in figuring out the right file in the first place.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can turn on `Show alternative source switcher` flag under **Settings >> Build, Execution, Deployment >> Debugger**.

Check **show alternative source switcher** check box, and IntelliJ IDEA will allow you to change required file.

Now, when you are debugging, IntelliJ IDEA should provide you other options to chose among source files.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue in eclipse, if you have answer for that also, please provide.

Comment: Checked the box, but couldn't find the place to switch files :-(

Answer (score 2):

To add on to the accepted answer, if you already have the setting checked but the alternative source switcher is not showing up, I found that toggling the setting off and back on bring the switcher up. On IDEA 2022.1.